# How do I save Apple Pay transaction on a customer?

Tags: stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I implemented Apple Pay into my app and it works fine, but currently when I use apple pay the transaction isn't linked to a user, when I add a customer/user parameter on my cloud code I get this error.

```
error:
type: "invalid_request_error"
message: "Customer cus_xxx does not have a linked card with ID tok_xxxx."
param: "card"
code: "missing"

Parse.Cloud.define("chargeApplePay", function(request, response){
Stripe.Charges.create({
amount: 100 * 100,
currency: "usd",
customer: request.params.idcustomer,
token: request.params.tokenid
},{
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success("success");
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error(httpResponse)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in a `token` parameter as the ID of the token you created, you could omit this parameter altogether when creating the charge and pass in only the `customer` parameter instead:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge-customer

This assumes that you already created a customer and saved that token as a payment source for that customer before making this charge:
https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later

If you do want to charge a specific card for that customer (as opposed to the default card on record), you'd pass in the card ID (card_*) as the `source`:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge-source

Comment: Since I am using apple pay, non of the cards are stored. I use `STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithPayment` instead of                 `STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard`

Comment: Stripe's iOS library just creates tokens; you need to either attach that token to a customer object using some server-side code (examples linked above -- doesn't matter if you're using Apple Pay or not), then create a charge, or pass that token in when creating a charge and omit the `customer` parameter altogether.

Comment: That's what I am currently doing. I am omitting the customer parameter, and it works fine, but when I do add the customer parameter I encounter this problem.

Comment: That's expected -- you'll get this error because you're attempting to charge a payment source that's not already attached to that customer object. In short, if you want to save the payment information for later use/create a charge against an existing customer object, you need to create a customer object and attach that token *first*. Otherwise, if you're just creating a single one-off charge, there's no reason to pass in a `customer` parameter at all.

Comment: So would it be possible to store a transaction instead of the card information to a customer?