# Is is possible to connect a transaction to a customer without the card being stored?

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

I am implementing Apple Pay into stripe and I can successfully make transactions, but those transactions are not linked to a customer. Is it possible to link a transaction to a customer without storing their credit card information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save Apple Pay transaction on a customer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951550/how-do-i-save-apple-pay-transaction-on-a-customer)

Answer (score 0):

No, the purpose of having customer objects in Stripe is essentially to store payment information for later use. If you're just creating one-off charges, there's no reason to create customer objects. You can read through the docs to get a better understanding of this here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers

Comment: Then how would I use apple pay? Do I have to store the credit card information? And if I do, how would it not save the card every time I use Apple pay?